# Use grandparent block

Tags: twig

I have the following twig templates:

```
{# layout.twig #}

{% block content %}
    THIS IS LAYOUT
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
{# secondary_layout.twig #}

{% extends layout.twig %}
{% block content %}
    THIS IS SECONDARY_LAYOUT
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
{# mypage.twig #}
{% extends secondary_layout.twig %}

{% block content %}
    {# I WOULD LIKE TO USE layout content block  here #}
{% endblock %}
```

I can call **parent()** inside the content block in mypage.twig, but how to use a grandparent instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok by writing the problem I got one solution, just modify secondary_layout

```
{# secondary_layout.twig #}

{% extends layout.twig %}
{% block content %}
    {% if use_layout_block %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% else %}
        THIS IS SECONDARY_LAYOUT
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
{# mypage.twig #}
{% extends secondary_layout.twig %}

{% block content %}
    {% set use_layout_block = true %}
{% endblock %}
```

It may help someone.

If someone got another solution, feel free to answer.

Comment: I'm even guessing this is the only way to do it

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help if the middle twig is a bundle file that you're extending and don't want to edit it directly.

Comment: @caponica This was exactly my problem too. But Med's solution gave me a good idea. I have solved by adding the use statement inside the block. Inside {# mypage.twig #}{% block content %} add {% "layout.twig" %}

Answer (score 8):

There are situations, in which you can achieve this. Unfortunately not in your case. However, it works if only "horizontal re-use" is used ([`use`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/use.html) keyword), but not with inheritance (`extends`). This for instance applies to form themes.

In my case I defined a form theme which inherits from the bootstrap 3 form theme. The bootstrap theme itself inherits from "form_div_layout". I wanted to override the choice widget and include the grand parent's (form_div_layout) block content, because the bootstrap version of the block didn't fit for me in this single case. So, basically a very similar problem.

This can be solved by inheriting from both, the parent (bootstrap_3_layout) and grand parent layout (form_div_layout), while declaring an alias for the grand parent block to be overridden:

```
{# my_form_theme.html.twig #}

{% use 'form_div_layout.html.twig' with choice_widget_collapsed as base_choice_widget_collapsed %}
{% use 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block choice_widget_collapsed -%}
    {# There is no "grandparent()" function, so instead we can do this:  #}
    {{- block('base_choice_widget_collapsed') -}}
{%- endblock %}
```

I'm writing this answer, although it doesn't answer the actual question. But other people will probably also find this question when googling for such a "grandparent"-feature and maybe they'll give up unnecessarily, when they read that it's impossible here.

Answer (score 2):

You can include the block of any template with the function block().
[block - Documentation - Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/block.html)

```
block(<block_name>, [template_name])
```

In your case, the solution could be as follows:

```
{# mypage.twig #}
{% extends secondary_layout.twig %}

{% block content %}
    {{ block('content', 'layout.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```